Cannot assign to '' because it is a read-only property for static readonly property in typescript
Consider the following class:
export class Foo {
  id: string;

  static readonly questionKeyPrefix: string;

  constructor(id: string, _key: string) {
    this.id = id;

    if (!Foo.questionKeyPrefix) {
      // Error: Cannot assign to 'questionKeyPrefix' because it is a read-only property
      Foo.questionKeyPrefix = _key;
    }
  }
}

When I try to set questionKeyPrefix which is a static readonly property, it complians. I also add the considition to make sure it is set only once!
If I remove the static everything will be fine!
Any idea how to fix this issue?
Playground

Why do you want to assign it in the constructor, when it is static? Is this for lazy initialisation?

In my Actual scenario, Foo is an abstract base class, and each derived class has its own unique key for its respective dictionary. To simplify initialization, it would be better to handle this in the constructor. Otherwise, there's a risk that developers might forget to call other static methods needed to initialize this property.

@kaya3 in C# I would use static constructor, but there is nothing like this in typescript!

But this code will not give different keys for different subclasses, all of the constructors will assign to the same field on the base class.

@kaya3 Why? In foo1: Foo and foo2: Foo I would expect that foo1 and foo2 has different keys. Am I wrong?

How can different instances have different keys when it is a static property?

@kaya3 You are right seems that my problem is complicated than I thought. Probably I need to add this static property to every single sub classes. But that also needs a huge refactor as I have a big application

Or you could just make it an instance property. Or if you are concerned about adding extra fields to every object, make it a method with get.

@kaya3 Actually I need to be static per each subclass

The way your code is designed at the moment, it can't work, because you have a static property whose value can change every time the constructor is invoked. Such a property cannot be readonly because its value can be observed to change after initialisation.
However, from the comments it seems this doesn't really model what you're trying to achieve, because you want this property to have a different value per subclass, just not a different value per instance.

The simplest solution is to make it an instance property regardless, and just give that instance property the appropriate value based on its subclass. An instance property doesn't need to be a constructor parameter for every subclass; you can pass it from the subclass's constructor:
class Base {
    // instance field
    readonly key: string;
    constructor(_key: string) {
        this.key = _key;
    }
}

class Foo extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super('Foo');
    }
}

class Bar extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super('Bar');
    }
}

Playground Link
An alternative, if you are concerned about this being a property (e.g. because it shows up when you serialize the object), is to make this a "virtual" property with get:
abstract class Base {
    abstract readonly key: string;
}

class Foo extends Base {
    get key() {
        return 'Foo';
    }
}

class Bar extends Base {
    get key() {
        return 'Bar';
    }
}

Playground Link
Since the getter is declared per subclass, the value is per subclass rather than per instance.

Generally speaking, "static per subclass" is not a very useful thing to do, because static properties are not normally accessed polymorphically. This would only make sense if the classes themselves were to be passed around as values, e.g.
interface KeyedClass {
    readonly key: string;
}

class Foo {
    static readonly key = 'Foo';
}

class Bar {
    static readonly key = 'Bar';
}

function logKey(cls: KeyedClass) {
    console.log(cls.key);
}

logKey(Foo);
logKey(Bar);

Playground Link
Assuming you aren't doing this, then there is no value in making something "static per class", because you can't access it polymorphically from an instance context. this.key won't work, and Base.key isn't polymorphic; you would just get the value of the base class's static property, regardless of what subclass this belongs to.

In TS you can use static blocks to initalize static members.
abstract class Foo {
    id: string;

    static questionKeyPrefix: string = "";

    constructor(id: string, _key: string) {
      this.id = id;    
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    static {
      Foo.questionKeyPrefix += "abc";
    }
}

console.log(Foo.questionKeyPrefix);

Unfortunately you Cannot assign readonly statics in static blocks #56584
